# Show S5 contains S4; Garson 2.4

Tags: modal-logic

<> = possible

[  ]=necessary

Hey all, I am trying to show the following axiom is provable in S5:

[  ]A -> [  ] [  ]A = (4)

The hint says to prove: [  ]A -> [  ] <> [  ]A first, which I have done:

1. [  ]A

2-) [  ]~[  ]A -> ~[  ]A         (instance M)

3-) [  ]A

4-) ~~ [  ]A                        (3, ~~In)

5-) ~[  ] ~[  ]A                    (2-4, MT)

6-) <>[  ]A                          (5, Def <>)

7-) <>[  ]A -> [  ]<>[  ]A         (instance of 5: <>P -> [  ]<>p)

8-) [  ]<>[  ]A   (6-7, MP)

9. [  ]A -> [  ]<>[  ]A    (1-8, CP)

I am stuck on the second leg, any help on how to prove [  ]<>[  ]A -> [  ][  ]A

---

**Question has been answered**

Comment: Make use of the fact that the contrapositive of axiom 5 is ◇□A → □A. Since this is a theorem, you then have □(◇□A → □A) by axiom N, and hence □◇□A → □□A by axiom K.

Comment: @Bumble if you dont mind putting that as an answer, so i can accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make use of the fact that the contrapositive of axiom 5 is ◇□A → □A. Since this is a theorem, you then have □(◇□A → □A) by axiom N, and hence □◇□A → □□A by axiom K

Comment: Just a question, though, can i introduce the contrapositive of 5 inside a boxed subproof? What rule should i list?

Comment: You can introduce it within the context of a supposition. I don't see why you need to here, though. You have proved □A → □◇□A and discharged the assumption □A, so just combine this with □◇□A → □□A using hypothetical syllogism.